# Ubuntu booting to blank screen

Tags: boot

I really wish to install Ubuntu to give it a try so I can ditch windows 10 if I enjoy it. However this happens every time I try to boot:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJYsSz7cVDw

Basically everytime I try to load it, all it does is say failed to load: Fecs-inst
And then It loads the desktop however it's completely blank.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

I'm using usb ubuntu 16.04 and my graphics is Nvidia GTX 960, my model is HP.

Here is a better picture of the only thing it says during boot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbp3i.jpg

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu, what installation media are you using (DVD/USB) and do you have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: We need more details in order to help you. What model computer is this? And what graphics does it have? This looks like a graphics issue to me...

Comment: Hello, I'm using usb and my graphics is Nvidia GTX 960, my model is HP.

Comment: @Navorn Pretty hard to see stuffs in the video because of a lack of focus. Any chance you can take pictures instead?

Comment: @edwinksl   http://imgur.com/7VKIX2E